# Perl6: Confused about BagHash/Matching

Tags: regex, raku, multiset

I'm attempting to count matches of a regex using a `BagHash`, and getting odd results.

```
my $fh = open "versions.txt";
my $versions = BagHash.new();

while (defined my $line = $fh.get) {
    my $last = '';
    if $line ~~ /(\d+)\.?(\d*)/ {
        say 'match ' ~ $/[0];
        if $last !eq  $/[0] {
            say 'not-same: ' ~ $/[0];
            $versions{$/[0]}++
        }
        $last = $/[0];
    }
    else {
        $last = '';
   }

}

say 'count: ' ~ $versions.elems;
```

Output is:

```
match 234
not-same: 234
match 999
not-same 999
count: 1 # I expect 2 here.
```

The test case I'm working with is:

```
version history thingy

version=234.234
version=999
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `!=` will coerce both arguments to `Num`. Do you want that?

Comment: I did not! However it seems that's not what's causing the problem. Edited to reflect the new version I just ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting $last with each iteration. Also, don't trust say. It's meant to be used to avoid flooding a terminal or logfile with infinite lists. Use `dd` (Rakudo internal) or a module to dump debug output. If you would have used `dd` would would have seen that `$/[0]` contains a `Match`, a complex structure that is not suited to generate Hash keys.

```
# my @lines = slurp('version.txt');
my @lines = ('version=234.234', 'version=999');
my BagHash $versions.=new;
for @lines {
    ENTER my $last = '';
    if .Str ~~ /(\d+) '.'? (\d*)/ {
        $versions{$0.Str}++ if $last ne $0.Str;
        $last = $0.Str
    }else{
        $last = ''
    }
};

dd $versions;
# OUTPUT«BagHash $versions = ("234"=>1,"999"=>1).BagHash␤»
```

The whole point of BagHash is that it's constructor will do the counting for you. If you supply lazy lists all the way down, this can be fairly efficient.

```
my @lines = ('version=234.234', 'version=999');
dd BagHash.new(@lines».split('=')».[1]);
# OUTPUT«("234.234"=>1,"999"=>1).BagHash␤»
```

Comment: The spec does not demand hyperops to be eager or lazy. They are defined as concurrent.

Comment: actually, hyper is like another notch on the lazy-eager scale; hyper is "even eagerer" than eager is, or at least hyper implies eager.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I'm going to suggest to the tutorial writer that they mention `dd` in addition to `say`.

Answer (score 4):

Bug #1 is you almost certainly want your `$last` declaration outside of the loop so you don't keep resetting it to `''`

Bug #2 you probably only want to update `$last` on the state where you found a version number not for all lines

Bug #3 you used the Match object as the key to the HashBag rather than the string value of the version. You can coerce a match to being the string it matched with `~$/[0]` but just `$0` is a shortcut for that too.

I cleaned up your code and got the below that works, but is really quite far from being idiomatic Perl 6:

```
my $fh = open "versions.txt";
my $versions = BagHash.new();

my $last = '';
for $fh.lines -> $line {
    if $line ~~ /(\d+)\.?(\d*)/ {
        say 'match ' ~ $/[0];
        if $last ne  $/[0] {
            say 'not-same: ' ~ $/[0];
            $versions{~$/[0]}++;
            $last = $/[0];
        }
    }
    else {
        $last = '';
   }

}
say $versions;
say 'count: ' ~ $versions.elems;
```

I would personally have written this as follows if it was throw away code:

```
my $versions = "versions.txt".IO.lines.comb(/(\d+)\.?(\d*)/).Bag; 
say $versions.elems;
```

If you wanted the file later or to do more with each line or this is for production:

```
my %versions;
for "versions.txt".IO.lines -> $line {
    if $line ~~ /((\d+)\.?(\d*))/ {
        %versions{$0}++;
    }
}
say %versions.elems;
```

Comment: I would also point out that `/ (\d+) [\. (\d+) ]? /` is probably what is wanted here. I would also use `my %versions is BagHash;`, or `my %versions := ...`

Comment: Very clear, thank you. Bug #2 is not a bug, btw, they're clusters of lines matching the regex (possibly multiple sequential lines that have the same pre-decimal value). Wanted to count the clusters with the same value--the test case was simplified.